# Multiple Resource Classes for REST using Jersey jax-rs

Tags: java, rest, http, jersey, jax-rs

I have two classes that are given as a resource to a jdk http server: Namenode and Datanode. Both have a different path, as can be seen on these interfaces:

```
@Path(Namenode.PATH)
public interface Namenode {

static final String PATH="/namenode";

@GET
@Path("/list/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
List<String> list( @QueryParam("prefix") String prefix);
// 200 OK [empty List]

@GET
@Path("/{name}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
List<String> read(@PathParam("name") String name);
// 200 OK | 404 Not Found

@POST
@Path("/{name}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
void create(@PathParam("name") String name, List<String> blocks);
// 204 No Content | 409 Conflict

@PUT
@Path("/{name}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
void update(@PathParam("name") String name, List<String> blocks);
// 204 No Content | 404 Not Found

@DELETE
@Path("/list/")
void delete( @QueryParam("prefix") String prefix);
// 204 No Content | 404 Not Found
}
```

and

```
@Path( Datanode.PATH ) 
public interface Datanode {

static final String PATH = "/datanode";

@POST
@Path("/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
String createBlock(byte[] data);
// 200 OK

@DELETE
@Path("/{block}")
void deleteBlock(@PathParam("block") String block);
// 204 No Content | 404 Not Found

@GET
@Path("/{block}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
byte[] readBlock(@PathParam("block") String block);
// 200 OK | 404 Not Found
}
```

They can be started at different times, and both should give access to their own methods regardless of status of the other resource.

On the constructor of each class, I start the jdk server like this:

```
// configs server
    ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig();

    config.register( DatanodeClass.class);
    config.register( NamenodeClass.class);


    try {
        JdkHttpServerFactory.createHttpServer( URI.create(URI_BASE), config);
    }catch(ProcessingException e) {
        // means server already up
    }
```

But this way of registering these resources doesn't actually define the other class, only it's own on the server. I get a MultiException of 2 whenever I use a method of the 2nd class being initialized, them being java.lang.NoSuchMethodException and IllegalArgumentException. How do I solve this? Any way I can add resources that are not yet started but will be?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace

Comment: And show the DatanodeClass and NamenodeClass